# bash script to compare number inside the 2 files

Tags: shell, bash

I want to compare 2 number from two different file using Bash script. The file is tmp$i  and tmp$(($i-1)). I have tried the script below is not working

```
 #!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 5`
do
    if [ $tmp$i -lt $tmp$(($i-1)) ];then
        cat tmp$i >> inf
    else
        cat tmp$i >> sup

    fi
done
```

Sample data
Tmp1:

```
0.8856143905954186 0.8186070632371812 0.7624440603372680 0.7153352945456424 0.6762383806114797 0.6405457936981878
```

Tmp2:

```
0.5809579333203458 0.5567050091247218 0.5329405222386163 0.5115305043007474 0.4963898045543342 0.4846139486344327
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: The sample data is as follow:

Tmp1:
      0.8856143905954186
       0.8186070632371812
       0.7624440603372680
       0.7153352945456424
       0.6762383806114797
       0.6405457936981878
and Tmp2
       0.5809579333203458
       0.5567050091247218
       0.5329405222386163
       0.5115305043007474
       0.4963898045543342
       0.4846139486344327

Comment: The sample data is as follow:

Tmp1:
      0.8856143905954186
       0.8186070632371812
       0.7624440603372680
       0.7153352945456424
       0.6762383806114797
       0.6405457936981878
and Tmp2
       0.5809579333203458
       0.5567050091247218
       0.5329405222386163
       0.5115305043007474
       0.4963898045543342
       0.4846139486344327

Comment: What do you want to compare? The first value in the file? When the first value always is < 1, you can try comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting `$tmp` so you end up simply comparing whether `i` is smaller than `i-1` which of course it isn't.

Removing the dollar sign nominally fixes that, but will just compare two strings (for which numeric cardinality isn't well-defined, so in practice, always false), not access the contents of files named like those strings.  `tmp2` is neither larger nor smaller than `tmp1`.  (Bash can perform lexical comparison, but `test ... -lt` isn't the tool to do that.)

Try this instead:

```
if [ $(cat "tmp$i") -lt $(cat "tmp$((i - 1))") ]; then
```

In response to the observation that you want to do this on decimal numbers, you need a different tool, because Bash only supports integer arithmetic.  My approach would be to write a simple Awk script which performs the comparison.

In order to be able to use it as a conditional, it should `exit(0)` if the condition is true, `exit(1)` otherwise.

In order to keep the main script readable, I would encapsulate it in a function, like this:

```
smaller_first_line () {
    awk 'NR==1 && FNR==1 { i=$1; next } FNR==1 { exit($1 < i) }' "$1" "$2"
}

if smaller_first_line "tmp$i" "tmp$((i - 1))"; then
    :
```

Comment: I have tried now the error is
./bash2.sh: line 4: [: 0.2224673048030570: integer expression expected
./bash2.sh: line 4: [: 0.2069661544333205: integer expression expected
./bash2.sh: line 4: [: 0.2231950007297217: integer expression expected
./bash2.sh: line 4: [: 0.2176809600890292: integer expression expected

Comment: Like it says, Bash only supports integer arithmetic. The easiest workaround might be to perform the comparison in an Awk script.